# Windows ACT/UAC - RunAsInvoker suddenly not helping

Tags: windows, startup, uac

I'm hoping someone can help. User Account Control and the Application Compatibility Toolkit have been driving me nuts all day...

I have a USB mouse with programmable buttons; when I first got it, I disovered that they wouldn't send keystrokes to an application running with administrator privileges unless the mouse monitor had also started with administrator privileges.

Without too much fuss, I implemented a workaround by marking monitor.exe to be run as admin, and then used the Application Compatibility Toolkit to set-up RunAsInvoker. Subsequently, the monitor started normally (via HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run) without a UAC prompt, and buttons mapped to keystrokes were sent to any other running application.

Since then, I've had to flatten the machine (more accurately: restore an image made before the mouse/workaround were installed). I've been trying various combinations of [basic] compatibility settings, registry hacks, and Compatibility Tool profiles for about the last 12 hours, but nothing will get keystrokes into apps running with admin rights.

Oddly, if I mark monitor.exe for 'run as administrator' (for my user or all users) in the compatibility tab on its properties page, and either apply RunAsInvoker by ACT or registry hack, the monitor starts without UAC prompt, but won't send keystrokes to other 'admin' apps. If I close it and restart it (without explicitly commanding 'as admin') there's no UAC prompt, and it won't send keystrokes. If I right click and 'run as admin', I get a UAC prompt, but keystrokes are sent just fine. When I 'test run' the monitor from the ACT wizard, there's no prompt and keystrokes work.(?!?)

I have no idea what I did differently the first time to make it work; so I'm really hoping [anyone still reading!] might have a tip or two for things to keep an eye out for.

Thanks for reading, and in advance for any help you can offer,

Rob.

EDIT: I should probably add, I had no joy with the scheduled task 'trick', either (not least because that way, the tray icon isn't available).

Comment: This question should be moved to superuser.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart [Apologies! - I did look for a more Windoze-admin focused area before posting, but somehow missed superuser.]

Comment: RunAsInvoker should have cancelled out "run as admin", and there isn't supposed to be any way (with just the tools provided by Microsoft) to make a program elevate without prompting.   My best guess would be that you had inadvertently turned UAC off altogether.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I'm certain I hadn't disabled UAC. A bit of Google-bashing found the blog I'd originally read: http://meridian.ws/wordpress/?p=306 - so while it might not be an 'official' sanctioned technique, I'm relieved I didn't imagine it. Unfortunately, I've tried again that exact way (and others) and had no luck.

Comment: Note to self: Don't press return in comments. <br/> (heh) I wondered if the mechanics are that invoker supersedes admin, but I didn't change the way the monitor was started. Still, on that thinking, I wonder if HKCU\..\Run might be better than HKLM with RunAsInvoker? I've just restored the image again to clear yesterday's bodges. Will try now...

Comment: Curious.  I'm 95% sure that the technique described isn't *supposed* to work, but I'll take your word for it that it did.  Perhaps Microsoft have patched the hole since then?

Comment: @HarryJohnston I'd almost be happy to find that it's a patch raining on my parade, but I've been re-imaging in short order lately, and not taking updates. I'm now more of the thinking that the admin part of that blog post is a red herring (with invoker doing the work), and that somehow whatever was invoking the process 'last time' had higher rights than whatever is now. The problem is, it was definitely using its default [HKLM]\Wow6432Node\Run reg entry last time. Would start by system, or my [admin] account? Only explicit run as admin or test run (inherited admin from ACT) work now :/

Comment: I've even tried starting it by a shortcut in my user account's startup folder (with RunAsInvoker set); figuring that it would certainly be started by my [admin] user account that way; still no joy.

Comment: I have a fix... Googling in desparation lead me to another question along similar lines; there was talk of scheduled tasks & services, then hiding at the bottom, mention of UACPass - https://sites.google.com/site/freeavvarea/UACPass-en - (with a mad interface) it does some scheduled task & batch file wizardry which while not very pretty, is functional enough. Found mouse's config app adds monitor to registry; I'm removing the entry after completing config to prevent double execution, but it seemed to cope without that belt & braces step. Thanks all who came along for the ride! @HarryJohnston

Comment: Right, but all of those require administrator setup before using. You cannot bypass the UAC prompt otherwise.